# Android custom list slow

Tags: java, android

Is there a better way to create a custom list, for my code here seems to make for a less-responsive list.  I can't use any of the standard Android lists because I need two ListView's in a ScrollView.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.alertsview);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    topRows = new ArrayList<View>();
    topLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.topListLayout);
    topLayout.removeAllViews();
    topRows.clear();
    List<Camera> camList = new ArrayList<Camera>(SitesOrchestrator.getInstance().currentSite.cameraList);

    for (int i = 0; i < camList.size(); i++)
    {
        Camera cam = camList.get(i);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameraalertrow, null);
        TextView name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.cameraNameAlerts);
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.camAlertChk);
        name.setText(cam.name);
        chk.setChecked(cam.alertsEnabled);
        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        String index = Integer.toString(i);
        chk.setTag(index);
        topRows.add(row);
        topLayout.addView(row);
    }
```

Comment: Unless camList is really small, this is always going to be slow and inefficient. You should rethink your UI and try to avoid two lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to lists in the same layout, you should create your own Adapter (derive from base adapter might be good), and, suppose you have two arraylist:

```
ArrayList<TypeA> typeAList;
ArrayList<TypeB> typeBList;

@Override
int getViewTypeCount(){ return 2; } // means you have two different views from it

@Override
int getItemViewType(int position){
    if (position>typeAList.size()) return 1;
    return 0;
}

getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    // Check the pos
    if (getItemViewType(pos) == 0){
        // Inflate view and bind for type A
    }
    else{
        // Inflate view and bind for type B
    }
}
```

In general, having two list view vertically is not encouraged in Android, but putting both of your content to one list do the trick. I also have a [tutorial](http://andytsui.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/tutorial-displaying-multiple-lists-in-one-single-listview-with-android-binding/) about this, though it is done in MVVM with [Android-Binding](http://code.google.com/p/android-binding/).

Moreover, adding Views one by one to ScrollView to mimic the ListView would, of course, be very inefficient. The way Android ListView works (which should different from desktop frameworks) is with recycling views. Suppose you are scrolling up, once the child is scroll out of sight, the listview will recycle the topmost one and place it to the bottom, and the possibly recycled view will pass as `convertView` in the above `getView` code. Inflating is considered to be quite expensive process, and multiple child views are memory consuming as well, that's the reason why your code, compare to standard ListView, is very inefficient.

Comment: Is there a reason why I would use a custom adapter in my custom list?  Is it simply to better manage de-queuing cells?

Comment: many lists, in Android, if you are binding some custom data to something more than just text, you need to write your own custom adapter. Writing adapter isn't that difficult, far easier than you manage your cells (well, that's you are writing your own ListView), take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html, which is one of the demo in API demo

Comment: P.S. In Android-Binding, I have a CombinedAdapter that takes unlimited list of Other adapters and make it into one: http://code.google.com/p/android-binding/source/browse/trunk/AndroidBinding/src/gueei/binding/collections/CombinedAdapter.java, you can use it as well (no need to be A-B)